# Write down the matrix of with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^4$ and $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be in $\mathbb R^4$ and let $W$ be in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $f$ be the linear map :

$$(x,y,z,t) \mapsto (x-2z+t,2y+z,x+4y+t)$$

Write down the matrix $A$ of $f$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^4$ and $\mathbb R^3$.

Find new basis for $\mathbb R^4$ and $\mathbb R^3$ with respect to which is the matrix of $f$ is :

$$B = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix} $$

Where these vectors form the rows of a matrix $B$.

What i have done so far is construct a matrix from the linear map f and reduced it to row echelon form to show that the rows are linearly independent. However, I am unsure of how to write down the matrix A with respect to the standard basis' given in the question.

More importantly how to find a matrix to which the matrix of f is the matrix B ?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the domain’s basis vectors expressed relative to the basis of the codomain. To find $A$, determine $f(\mathbf e_i)$ for each of the standard basis vectors $\mathbf e_i$ of $\mathbb R^4$. Each resulting vector will be the corresponding column of $A$.

To find the matrix $B$, use the same principle: its columns are the images of some basis of $\mathbb R^4$ expressed relative to some basis of $\mathbb R^3$. The last two columns of $B$ are zero, so those two basis vectors must lie in the kernel (nullspace) of $f$. You can see from $B$ that its nullity is two, so these vectors are also a basis of $\ker(f)$. So, start by choosing a basis for this subspace.

Now, for the other two vectors (call them $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$). The first two columns of $B$ are the identity. For this to happen, we must have $\{f(\mathbf v_1),f(\mathbf v_2)\}$ as the basis for the image of $f$. So, extend the basis that you chose above for the kernel to a complete basis for $\mathbb R^4$ and set the first two vectors of the basis for $\mathbb R^3$ to $f(\mathbf v_1)$ and $f(\mathbf v_2)$, respectively. You need one more vector to complete this basis—choose any vector not in the image of $f$. Once you’ve done this, check your work by applying the change-of-basis formula to $A$. You should end up with $B$.

Note that the choice of bases is not unique. You have a lot of freedom in selecting a basis for the domain, and this choice only determines part of the basis for the codomain.